# Celery with MongoDB result backend and Neo4j storage

Tags: python, mongodb, neo4j, celery

I have some Celery workers that store their results in a MongoDB backend. This seems to be working very well. However, I also need to store the unique taskID (along with some other task result meta data) in a Neo4J graph database.

My primary objective is to have a reference to the task results from within Neo4J without cluttering it with thousands of results. Thus, Neo4J provides a visualisation capability for the task results.

I need some advice on the best approach for achieving this using Celery.

Here are some of the options I've been toying with:

1. Use Celery's sub-tasking and create separate tasks that are handled by separate workers to send the data to Neo4J.
2. Use Celery's HTTP Callback Tasks (Webhooks) to post the data directly to Neo4J's REST API
3. Extend the primary tasks to include a call to Neo4J's REST API

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It's not clear if you are asking about organization of data in Neo4j and MongoDB or asking how to store additional information in Neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queuing a call to Neo4J as a subtask improves [granularity of tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#granularity) with trade off in consistency (data in Neo4J will be catching up with data in MongoDB).

You can subclass `celery.Task` and override [celery.Task.after_return](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.after_return) so it saves `task_id` to Neo4J. Note, that `retval` can be an uncaught exception.